# Balls and bins -- concentration bounds pertaining to the minimal load bin

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, measure-concentration

Consider the standard balls and bins process, where $m$ balls are thrown uniformly at random into $n$ bins. Previous work has been done on estimating the value of the maximum load (i.e., the number of balls in a bin at the end of the process), where tight concentration bounds on $w_{max}$ are given as a function of $m$ and $n$.

My question is: can one provide similar bounds on the $w_{min}$, or even better, provide a good estimate of the distribution of $w_{min}$. Clearly, one can upper-bound the LHS-tail of the distribution of $w_{min}$, using the standard Chernoff and union bounds, but this is not good enough for what I need.

*Generalizing this even further*, I want to estimate the following: let $k \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, I am interested in estimating the concentration of weight of a randomly sampled set bins of size $k$ containing the minimal-load bin.

Comment: Suppose we find $P_r$("at least e bins out of m are empty after  the n balls have been thrown"); will that suffice? 0 in any case is the lower lim of $w_{min}$

Comment: ..."Previous work has been done on estimating the value of the maximum load" : any references ?

Comment: http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/peer2peer/math/balls-into-bins.pdf

Comment: As it turns out, one could use the Poisson approximation to estimate the distribution of the minimum load. (cf. Corollary 5.11 in p. 103 in [link](http://books.google.ca/books?id=0bAYl6d7hvkC&pg=PA104&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false). 

Asked a similar question about $n$ Poisson variables in a separate post:[link](http://mathoverflow.net/q/136222/36530)

Comment: @R B , The first question can have a tight bound for $w_{max},w_{min}$ simultaneously if we treat the throwing process as one transition and use the exchangeable pair technique mentioned in *[Lester Mackey et.al]Matrix concentration inequalities via the method of exchangeable pairs*; The second question of Poisson approximation can be answered by the result mentioned here (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1022696125272) The third question of randomizing $k$ is no more than a two-layer hierachy model if I understand it correctly?

Comment: @JoelO And what do you mean by "good enough" bound? The Gaussian-majorized bound can be obtained using chaining, See p.210 of (http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/teaching/2015-16/626/HDP-book.pdf)

Comment: The limiting distributions of the maximal and minimal loads are described
in chapter 2, §6  of the book "Random allocations" by Kolchin, Sevast'yanov and Chistyakov

Comment: Possibly not relevant or maybe too specific: this preprint
https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07635 gives a pretty good formula
for the asymptotic likelihood for specified minima. This is 
done first for random sets, and then the corresponding balls and bins problem, while different, is shown to have the same asymptotic behaviour. I have no idea whether any of this is new.